# How to dynamically add rows to html table after uploading files using dropzone without refreshing page?

Tags: python, flask, dropzone

I am new to flask and dropzone.

I have created a `flask` application using `dropzone` to allow user to drop files. I am extracting text from dropped files and extracted text will go to my **Azure ML web service** for document classification. This web service will return with `Prediction result` and `Scored probabilities` that i want to display to the user in a HTML table.

Here, what user will have is a web page having `drop interface` and a blank `html table`. User will drop a file and result will appear as a table row. I do not want to redirect to the new page because user might upload multiple files (e.g 100 files) and only few files will be processed (e.g 5 files parallelly). So results for each request should be a table row and each row should append to the table.

Below are my files:

**flask-interface.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, patch_request_class, ALL

url = 'azure url'
api_key = 'api key'
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key)}

app = Flask(__name__)
dropzone = Dropzone(app)

# Dropzone settings
app.config['DROPZONE_UPLOAD_MULTIPLE'] = True
app.config['DROPZONE_PARALLEL_UPLOADS'] = 5
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for key, f in request.files.items():
            // save files

        // Calling Azure Web Service

        // Reading response
        return render_template('result.html', result=response)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Flask Interface</title>
        {{ dropzone.load() }}
        {{ dropzone.style('border: 2px dashed #0087F7; margin: 10%; min-height: 200px;') }}
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Please Drag and Drop file(s) to test ML Studio web service.</h2>
        {{ dropzone.create(action_view='index') }}
        <div id="content">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>Prediction Result</th>
                        <th>Score Probability</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>            
                <tbody>
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for dict in result %}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ dict['Scored Labels'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ dict['Scored Probabilities'] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`result.html` is a child of `index.html` and trying to add rows dynamically.

How can i add response as rows inside existing table without refreshing page?

Comment: Hey Nilesh, did you ever get this figured out? Interested in doing the same thing with an app I'm making!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing `return render_template('result.html', result=response)`, you could return a `Response` containing that information. I'm not really familiar with dropzone, but I'm going to assume it has the possibility to add some JavaScript callback function to it for when the flask server returns a response. Something in the lines of

```
dropzone.onResponse((response) => {
  const rows = convertResponseToRows();
  const table = document.getElementById('the-table');
  rows.forEach((row) => addRowToTable(table, row));
});
```